# Access Control of class members. Direct access vs explicit Getter and Setter

Tags: swift, oop, setter, getter, access-control

We have a lot of blogs, where Swift and it's awesomeness is discussed. Most of them sound like a whole WWDC and don't discuss their topics in an exhausting way and a critical point of view. So this question is explicit for the free thinking minds, the stackoverflow community ;-)

In Swift we have access control mechanisms like

```
public private(set) var foo: Foo?
```

and

```
private var _foo: Foo?
public var foo: Foo? {
  get {
    // make some preparing stuff, in another kind of way, as in the setter
    return _foo
    // make some completing stuff, in another kind of way, as in the setter
  }
  willSet {
    // make some preparing stuff
  }
  set {
    _foo = newValue
  }
  didSet {
    // make some completing stuff
  }
```

The common way in OOP for this purpose is

```
private var foo: Foo?
  public getFoo() -> Foo? {
    // make some preparing stuff, in the same kind of way, as in the setter
    return foo
    // make some completing stuff, in the same kind of way, as in the setter
  }
  private setFoo(foo: Foo) {
    // make some preparing stuff
    self.foo = foo
    // make some completing stuff
}
```

What do you think about these mechanisms, considering following questions?

1. Why `willSet`and `didSet` but no `willGet`and `didGet`?
2. Is there no better way than these double defining variables `foo`and `_foo`?
3. `public private(set)` gives good access control, but the IDE Xcode shows suggestions to the variable, when typing `myInstance.foo =` from outside the declaring class. No Error or warning is shown until you assign a new value.
4. After assigning the new value, Xcode says the `setter is inaccessible`. In OOP usually visibility is checked at first. Swift seems not to know what visibility is. Obviously it's not possible to determine if `myInstance.foo` will be completed to  an "read command" `myInstance.foo.bar` or a "write command". What do you think about this lack of useful code completion?
5. Has anyone doe's performance checks aiming at the use of explicit getters and setters?
6. Is it a good idea to  use computed variables. They are in fact nothing else than the results of methods/functions.
7. Apple and it's community promote the meaningfulness or awesomeness of these techniques intensively. a) Is it bad to use traditional Getters and Setters? b) Why does Apple use "their" approach in common iOS UserInterface Classes (`textField.text = "foo"`), in contrast to their youngest classes in the UserInterface of the WatchKit (`textField.setText("foo")`)? Is it a step back of forward?

So. These are many questions, but I thinks, at least these are relevant, to get an overview. I'm looking forward for your aspects.